# How can I access or expose the Commerce data in $order->data[] to the Rules module?

Tags: 7, forms, commerce, rules

Following this old [checkout_pane_example.module](https://web.archive.org/web/20160328130602/http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce_examples!checkout_pane_example!checkout_pane_example.module/DC) tutorial,  I created a custom Drupal 7 Commerce checkout pane. It's simply a text field to collect special order instructions from the customer.

```php
function checkout_pane_example_pane_checkout_form($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {

  $pane_form['nickname'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#title' => t('Your nickname'), 
    '#description' => t("We'd like to call you by your nickname."), 
    '#default_value' => !empty($order->data['nickname']) ? $order->data['nickname'] : '', 
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  return $pane_form;
}
```

The pane works fine. Anything that's saved in the text area is then stored in `$order->data['nickname']`.

The problem is that I need to access the data in Rules so I can attach it to the existing email that's sent out on order completion email.

How can I access or expose that data via the Rules module?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really expose `data` as such, but you can define your own order property via `hook_entity_property_info()` with a custom callback that returns the specific value from the `data` array you want.

For an example, take a look at `commerce_order_entity_property_info()`'s definition of the `mail_username` property and the related `commerce_order_get_properties()` callback.